# Send to tray on Close

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, system-tray

How can I send the window minimized to tray when on click close button?
Also how to show icon in tray when application start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing that comes embedded with WPF. From implementations that you can find on the net, there is an "easy" one, that uses WinForms:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972170.aspx

But I like this one more (can be used for balloon tips too)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_notifyicon.aspx

Answer (score 8):

**WinForm:**

One approach is to set the Cancel property of FormClosingEventArgs in the FormClosing event of your window and instead minimize to tray.  For minimizing to tray, see this article:

[Window Tray Minimizer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Trayminimizer.aspx)

Code Project has more articles on the topic, but the one I linked worked for me.

**WPF:**

I've never had to do this in WPF but did poke around for a solution.  I found this:

[Creating a Tray Icon for a WPF Application](http://www.pandemoniumincarnate.com/category/wpf/)

You'll find the code works but I recommend testing.  The article addresses opening an application minimized to the tray.

You might also find this sample on MSDN useful:

[Notification Icon Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972170.aspx?ppud=4)

Comment: This one is not easy to attach to a WPF app.

Comment: You're right Sergey.  I Googled and found some resources but nothing I'd consider fully satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

In winforms you can overload WndProc and watch for the WM_CLOSE message.

```
    WM_CLOSE = 0x0010

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
      if(m.Msg == WM_CLOSE)
      {
        this.Hide();
        trayIcon.Show();
      }

    }
```