# WiX call app on uninstall before User prompt "close manually"

Tags: windows, installation, wix

I got an installer which installs an application and starts this one right after the installation was finished. This works properly for me.

But now I want to stop that application while uninstalling the application, i don't want the user to be prompted to close applications manually. This shall work full automatic.

I ned to do this using a custom action, the WM_CLOSE message will not work in my approach (really, i tried it a couple of times).

I thought that this can't be that difficult, but I don't get it to work. What I did so far:

I defined a CustomAction:

```
<CustomAction Id="CloseTrayApp" ExeCommand="-exit" FileKey="TrayApp" Execute="immediate" Return="asyncNoWait" />
```

and called it liek this:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
...
    <Custom Action="CloseTrayApp" Before="InstallValidate" />
...
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

But this does not work. I guess that I'm sheduling my custom action wrong, but I can't figure out the correct time to do it.

Are there any suggestions regarding the time/place to shedule the custom action in? I'm quite unsure if

```
Before="InstallValidate"
```

is the right place to do it.

Comment: when you say "this doesn't work" - what do you mean? any errors in the log file?

Comment: How can i view the logfile? Doesn't work means, that I still get the "close apps manually" dialog, the installer says it failed and the process is still running.

Comment: in order to generate the verbose log file you should run the installation with /l*v command line switch. Like this: `msiexec /i MyApplication.msi /l*v MyLogFile.txt`

Comment: possible duplicate of [WiX close application before uninstall - close open applications message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822010/wix-close-application-before-uninstall-close-open-applications-message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [FilesInUse Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) help topic, before InstallValidate is the correct place to schedule the custom action.  But I'm confused as to why the WM_CLOSE won't work for you.  I saw you asked another question and accepted it as the answer.  Perhaps your TrayApp could have a "hidden" form that the user never sees but is running to receive the WM_CLOSE message.  This is a trick I've done many times over the years.

Otherwise, if you really want to call your EXE, I suggest never using an EXE custom action.  Instead use the [Quiet Execution Custom Action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm).  For some reasons on why to do this see [Integration Hurdles for EXE Custom Actions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2007/10/20/integration-hurdles-for-exe-custom-actions.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your reply, i've already tried to use a hidden form, but i experienced that every time i triggered some action from my task bar icon, the wm_close message was send, and therefore the application was closed because i'm not able to make up a difference between an uninstaller wm_close message and a common wm_close message